# How to correct write a file to the sd card?

Tags: java, android

I use the [library](https://github.com/Coolerfall/Android-HttpDownloadManager) to download files. By default, all downloaded files in the `Downloads` folder retains the phone's `internal memory`. Everywhere they say that it is possible to write files in the `SD-card` in this way:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + File.separator
```

And also wrote about it in the `README`:

```
.destinationFilePath (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + File.separator)
```

But be that as it did not change, still writes the downloaded files to the internal memory.

Prompt, please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the documentation of `getExternalStorageDirectory`